# BitmapImage's ImageOpened event not fired in background agent

Tags: c#, events, windows-phone-8, background-agents

As in the title, the event is not fired when the code is executed in the `BackgroundAgent` while it works fine when I execute it in my main app.

Here's my code:

```
var background = new BitmapImage(new Uri(uri), UriKind.Absolute)){ CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
background.ImageFailed += (s, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e);
    // Nothing happens here so I guess that there's no error in the image loading
};
background.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("ImageOpened");
    // This line is never printed no the event is never thrown
};
```

Everthing is running in a `Dispatcher` thread, and I'm trying to load a remote image (I can't cache it because it's a dynamic image generated by a `php` page).

Any hint?

EDIT:

Here's the code based on @l3arnon's suggestion:

```
var backgroundImage = new BitmapImage { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
backgroundImage.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
                Debug.WriteLine("ImageOpened");
};
backgroundImage.UriSource = new Uri(uri);
```

still no success though.

Comment: Where are you registering an event handler to the ImageLoaded event?

Comment: Actually I was talking about the `ImageOpened` event, I just edited the title

Comment: I am trying to catch ImageFailed event and it is never firing for local files. I tried it with text file with `.gif` extension, tried with non existing path. Nothing. Could be that your's is not firing neither.

Comment: Seeing the same issue with Silverlight currently, did you get anywhere with this? Intermittent issue with ImageFailed/ImageLoaded not firing

Answer (score 1):

My only guess it that it loads the image so fast that you register the event handler too fast.
Try first creating the BitmapImage instance and then setting a uri